# Como lidar com classcasting de Scala x Java

Tags: java, herança, scala

Estou tendo um problema para trabalhar com herança entre Scala e Java.

Para contextualizar, segue um exemplo que reflete meu problema.

- Java Class

```java
public class Animal {
}
```

- Java Class

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
}
```

- Scala class

```scala
class Dog extends Animal {
}
```

- Java class

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal1 = new Dog(); //Java's Animal receives Scala's Dog reference
    Animal animal2 = new Cat(); //Java's Animal receives a Java's Cat reference
  }
}
```

Recebo este erro acerca da conversão Dog x Animal:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dog to Animal
```

Porém o mesmo não acontece com a classe Cat.

Alguém poderia me fazer a gentileza de explicar o que está acontecendo aqui?

Comment: Por alguma razão eu só reiniciei meu computador e funcionou. Parece que eu estava com um problema de classpath.